# Awk: How do I output data from two files

Tags: awk

So yeah im trying to match file1 that contains email to file2 that cointains email colons address, how do i go on bout doing that?

tried  `awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$0; next}{print a[$1] $0}'` but idk what im doing wrong

file1:

```
email@email.email
email@test.test
test@email.email
```

file2:

```
email@email.email:addressotest
email@test.club:clubbingson
test@email.email:addresso2
```

output:

```
test@email.email:addresso2
email@email.email:addressotest
```

Comment: Show your efforts and then get the answer !

Comment: i've tried  awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$0; next}{print a[$1] $0}' file1 file2  but does not work

Comment: Post some sample data with expected output, please. We don't enjoy the quessing game.

Comment: sorry about that, I added data

Comment: You need to set the field separator for file2. Try `awk -F: [your code here] file1 file2`.

Comment: is there an output sorting criteria???

Answer (score 1):

Following `awk` may help you in same.

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$0];next} ($1 in a)' FILE_1 FS=":" FILE_2
```

Comment: @JohnnyB, it worked for me, what error are you getting?

Comment: Im not getting any errors, the command responds as if no matches were found

Comment: @JohnnyB, did you run the exact command? It is working fine for me.

Comment: I tried it with the examples I provided, it works, but when I try it with my actual files, it does not work. (the files I have are big files)

Comment: Then the files probably differ from samples somehow. How big are the files?

Comment: @JohnnyB, solutions will be given as per shown samples only, so make sure your SAMPLE is near to your ACTUAL in format may not be in size in you posts, please post sample again and let me know then.

Answer (score 1):

`join` with presorting input files

```
$ join -t: <(sort file1) <(sort file2)

email@email.email:addressotest
test@email.email:addresso2
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey why going for a `awk` solution when you can simply use the following `join` command:

```
join -t':' file 1 file2
```

where join as its names indicate is just a file joining command and you chose the field separator and usually the input columns and output to display (here not necessary)

Tested:

```
$more file{1,2}
::::::::::::::
file1
::::::::::::::
email@email.email
email@test.test
test@email.email
::::::::::::::
file2
::::::::::::::
email@email.email:addressotest
email@test.club:clubbingson
test@email.email:addresso2

$join -t':' file1 file2
email@email.email:addressotest
test@email.email:addresso2
```

If you need to sort the output as well, change the command into:

```
join -t':' file 1 file2 | sort -t":" -k1
```

or

```
join -t':' file 1 file2 | sort -t":" -k2
```

depending on which column you want to sort upon (eventually add the `-r` option to sort in reverse order.

```
join -t':' file 1 file2 | sort -t":" -k1 -r
```

or

```
join -t':' file 1 file2 | sort -t":" -k2 -r
```

Comment: I've tried this, but I get

join: file2.txt: 4 is not sorted:  email@email.email:addressotest
join file1.txt:2: is not sorted: test@email.email

Comment: what is your sorting criteria?

Comment: @JohnnyB I have edited my answer please have a look! ;-)

Comment: you have to sort input files!